# GTK detecting window resize from the user

Tags: gtk, signals, resize

In GTK (or pygtk or gtkmm...)

How can I detect that an application window has been **manually** resized by the user, as is typically done by dragging the window's edge?

I need to find a way to differentiate manual resizes from resizes that originate from gtk, such as changes in window content.

Comment: Have you figured out a way to do this?

Comment: No.  If I do, it'll show up here.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Have you tried connecting to the GDK_CONFIGURE event?

Check out [this example](http://zetcode.com/gui/gtk2/gtkevents/) under the
"Moving window" section.  The example shows a callback doing something when the window is moved, but the configure event is a catch-all for moving, resizing and stack order events.

Comment: The following code works for this:
g_signal_connect(G_OBJECT(window), "configure-event", G_CALLBACK(callback_func), NULL);

Comment: I think you can use "check-resize" instead "configure-event"

Comment: But this doesn't provide a way to check what type of event occurred: resize or move. So surely if the user does not somehow find a way to determine that, this will produce spurious results. @boldnik: According to this, that will not work, as it fires for all kinds of other reasons: https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1100803&p=6927690#post6927690

Comment: The given link is dead and the edit queue is full. Here's the current link to the example given: http://zetcode.com/gui/gtk2/

Comment: @boldnik check_resize is triggered constantly at my side. I think configure-event is most likely the right direction.

Answer (score 7):

I managed to pull this off by watching for `size_allocate` and `size_request` signals on the `GtkWindow`.  If `size_request` ever got smaller, I called `resize(1,1)`.  If `size_allocate` was ever bigger than expected, I turned the system off.

One thing I made sure to handle was `size_request` returning big, then small, and having `size_allocate` be big and then small.  I don't know if this is possible, but I fixed it by making sure to only decrease the expected values for `size_allocate` when I got a smaller `size_allocate`, not when I got a smaller `size_request`.

Make sure that your `size_request` handler comes after the base class' handler so that you get the right values.  I did this by overriding the method and then calling the base class method first.

I've tried this in both 1 and 2 dimensions and it seems to work either way.

Answer (score 5):

In my case I was trying to distinguish between a user resizing a Gtk.Paned from the user resizing the whole window. Both emitted the `notify::position` signal.

My solution was, since I can't know if the user is resizing the window from the widget, reverse what I wanted to know. Record if the user has re-positioned the widget and ignore updates if the user didn't initiate them on my widget.

That is to say, instead of testing "if window being resized" I recorded the `button-press-event` and `button-release-event`'s locally so I could instead test "if widget being re-positioned"

```py
from gi.repository import Gtk

class MyPaned(Gtk.Paned):
    _user_activated = False

    def on_position(self, _, gparamspec):
        if self._user_activated:
            # widget touched

        else:
            # window resized (probably)

    def on_button_press(self, *_):
        self._user_activated = True

    def on_button_release(self, *_):
        self._user_activated = False


    dev __init__(self, *args):
        super(MyPaned, self).__init__(*args)
        self.connect('notify::position', self.on_position)
        self.connect('button-press-event', self.on_button_press)
        self.connect('button-release-event', self.on_button_release)
```

Effectively by recorded when the user started and ended interacting with my widget directly, I could assume the rest of the time was due to the window being resized. (Until I find more cases)

Comment: Where in the API reference can I find the `notify::position`?

Comment: @buhtz I think I stumbled into a "notify::<type>" example in the wild, and I inferred the rest for Lazka's awesome PGI Docs:
 https://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/#Gtk-3.0/classes/Paned.html

Comment: @ThorSummoner In the docs I nowhere can find a `notify::*` event. That is why I am wondering about.

Comment: @ThorSummoner Yes, I wanted to add python3 syntax highlighting in your code snippet but SE tells me the *edit queue* of your answer is full.

Comment: @ScroogeMcDuck I've made the edited (great suggestion) maybe this clears the edit queue? I didn't see anything obvious about how to resolve that when I looked at the edit history of this answer

Comment: If there is a user that uses a tiling window manager, this code will not work as expected

Answer (score 4):

In PyGTK, I've always watched for the `expose_event` for a window resize, then use the `get_allocation` method to get the new size.

Comment: I'm looking at the GdkEventExpose structure...is it the send_event field that would tell me the user did it?

Comment: Actually, you probably want event_configure, not event_expose... my bad.  I think that's called for both moves and resizes, so you'll have to remember the previous size if that's all you're interested in.

Answer (score 1):

You may be able to throw something together by using [gdk_window_get_root_origin](http://library.gnome.org/devel/gdk/stable/gdk-Windows.html#gdk-window-get-root-origin) to get the top left corner of the window and [gdk_window_get_geometry](http://library.gnome.org/devel/gdk/stable/gdk-Windows.html#gdk-window-get-geometry) to get the width and height.  Then you could hook a callback into the GDK_BUTTON_PRESS_MASK and check to see if the button press occurs near/on one of the edges of the window.

Of course, this seems quite hackish and it really bothers me that I couldn't find some simple way in the documentation for GdkWindow to do this.  There is a [gdk_window_begin_resize_drag](http://library.gnome.org/devel/gdk/stable/gdk-Windows.html#gdk-window-begin-resize-drag) function which *really* makes me think there's a cleaner way to do this, but I didn't see anything more obvious than my answer.